# Could you help me with typing my own variant of Reduce function

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics, reduce

I wrote down my own version of `Array.prototype.reduce` function. But works out of the global Array. The function signature looks like below. There are three cases of using this function

```js
function reduce<T> (
  arr: T[],
  reduceFunction: (acc: T, item: T, index: number, arr: T[]) => T,
): T;

function reduce<T> (
  arr: T[],
  reduceFunction: (acc: T, item: T, index: number, arr: T[]) => T,
  initialValue: T,
): T;

function reduce<T, R> (
  arr: T[],
  reduceFunction: (acc: R, item: T, index: number, arr: T[]) => R,
  initialValue?: R
): R;
```

But how I can conditionally type my `initialValue` and `acc` parameters so the prev variable will be accepted without an error

[**Typescript Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKYBMQVQHgCoB8AFAFCLmICGyyAXIngNoC6ANGRWptgGLjTww9IpQgR6eVohhRUAWwlSYYdKgAe9MCDkAjVMinU6DFgEpEAXgIN2piSRKhIsBCgxZchUhSo0JLdh8uDz5nQWFRcRtpWQVo5VUNRC1dfUM-E2ZzKxsOcmUZGEoAGwA1EpBURRI7BgcnAVdg7HwpACViPN9jJjYu5tRQxqFEETF6NqVYxWkVdU1tPQNu-yzLa0mugtgS8uLKiZrDx34XJAHWxA7vCiNVwM53XlPw0ciJxAAfeOn4uaSUkt0j0zOsrl9cj5tkUyhVUAB%20D7fPBHcHIxAAby2wFG0N2cMsFgsiHAqmAygw5ixPh8xVQUEQAAc0AA3SzdRgABmYDhpFGAcGQozpDJg7IAjABuaSIHDdAB0dLAAHMoAALaUwADUWqpXT55AgCAAzqLYuyjIwYDyDTTmag2cSBkMzkR7SypvIlMDTPqKABfXkGtBQEDIJDurr%20xCoYrG1CYv3kEVM1nsvGw-aoIN8gVCogpsXEzma2UKpWqjXSHV620%20I1gU0xeQWmhWnlJu1pp1PQYvBBu1meuTe7q%2022BzshsMR1lRkj%20oA)

```js
function reduce<T> (
  arr: T[],
  reduceFunction: (acc: T, item: T, index: number, arr: T[]) => T,
): T;

function reduce<T> (
  arr: T[],
  reduceFunction: (acc: T, item: T, index: number, arr: T[]) => T,
  initialValue: T,
): T;

function reduce<T, R> (
  arr: T[],
  reduceFunction: (acc: R, item: T, index: number, arr: T[]) => R,
  initialValue?: R
): R;

function reduce<T, R> (
  arr: T[],
  reduceFunction: (acc: R | T, item: T, index: number, arr: T[]) => R | T,
  initialValue?: R | T
): R | T {
  if (initialValue === undefined) {
    let prev = arr[0]

    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
      const item = arr[i]
      // Type 'T | R' is not assignable to type 'T'.'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T | R'.ts(2322)
      prev = reduceFunction(prev, item, i, arr)
    }

    return prev
  } else {
    let prev = initialValue as R

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      const item = arr[i]
      
      

// let prev: (T & ({} | null)) | (R & ({} | null))
// Type 'T | R' is not assignable to type '(T & ({} | null)) | (R & ({} | null))'.
// Type 'T' is not assignable to type '(T & ({} | null)) | (R & ({} | null))'.
// Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T & null'.
// Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'null'.ts(2322)
      prev = reduceFunction(prev, item, i, arr) as R
    }

    return prev
  }
}



const result = reduce<User, UserWithFullname[]>(
  arr,
  (acc, item) => {
    return [...acc, { ...item, fullname: item.name + ' ' + item.surname }]
  },
  []
)

const total = reduce(
  products,
  (acc, item) => {
    return acc + item.capacity * item.price
  },
  0
)

console.log(result)
console.log(total)
```

Comment: And is there any chance to make Generic types optional,  so It took T type from array item type and there will be no need to specify it explicitly when using the function. l

Comment: Are you just looking for [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wok1lW) where you annotate `prev` as `T | R` so that the compiler expects such things?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?